# How to send Post request to a php file i react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in reactjs.  I want to know How to send an ajax request to server(php file)? 
the structure of my project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ynFD.png)

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class User extends React.Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={username:'someone'}
}
click_btn=()=>{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");

}
render() {
    return(
        <div><h1>{this.state.username}</h1>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.click_btn}>show</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

It returns status 404 and error Can not post insert.php!
where I should locate my insert.php or how address it?

Answer (score 1):

make a php folder and move the php file inside - and this should work.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type:"POST",
    url:"php/insert.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(this.state), 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        console.log("Added");
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
});
```

or

```
fetch('php/insert.php', { // URL
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state), // data you send.
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    redirect: 'follow', // *manual, follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
})
.then(function(response) {
    // manipulate response object
    // check status @ response.status etc.
    return response.json(); // parses json
})
.then(function(myJson) {
    // use parseed result
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

Comment: make it in public directory or src directory or upper? @Àtishking

Comment: @Jmx public directory is fine.

Comment: But you are using GET Instead of POST!?

Comment: @Jmx upadting the answer now

Answer (score 0):

I should locate PHP files in PHP server